# click on link via selenium

Tags: selenium

Using selenium (server using eclipse), I need to locate a link on a webpage e.g. this is link  and then click on the link.  What would be the best approach to do so - thanks in advance for any useful suggestions.

Edit:  The link itself is not static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simply use the following:

selenium.click("link=log in"); //where "log in" is the text for the link

Answer (score 1):

Assumption is that the link text changes but the position remains same.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css")).click();